# VB.NET and calling byval/byref C# overloads

Tags: c#, vb.net, byref, method-resolution-order, byval

We have a C# class, which includes two functions, whose parameters differ only by the parameter modifier:

```
bool DoSomething(Object obj){};
bool DoSomething(ref Object obj){};
```

Now we need to call this method (any of them, actually) from VB.NET. The problem is that the VB.NET compiler can't decide, which method to use.

The question is: is there a way to tell the compiler that we want the first variant (or the second one, it doesn't matter for the caller)?

Writing the call as `DoSomething((myObj))` (i.e. adding parentheses) in VB.NET doesn't help.

Comment: IMO that seems like a bad API design.

Comment: commenting to track. so C# considers it a different function signature having the same return type and same number and type of parms? seems odd like it shouldn't do that...

Comment: best way i can think of is DoSomethingByRef(ref object)

Comment: You could likely call the correct one using reflection (though I have not personally tried it) using the methods described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s2kzbw8(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parametermodifier(v=vs.110).aspx). I would still echo what others have said here and look at changing your API design to better distinguish the methods, especially since this is visible to VB.Net code.

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly. It's similar to trying to differentiate between two methods whose names differ only in casing. It is not a feature that is supported in all languages, so it is considered poor form and is not CLS compliant. For example, [see this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/15734064-byref-overloading-in-vb) and [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/170).

Comment: @DanielA.White there were reasons to do this, and VB.NET was not on the radar. Reflection was the solution, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a separate library written in C# that provides helper methods with distinct names to enable you to call the ambiguously defined `DoSomething` methods. You shouldn't have to do that, and people might wonder why you did, so you could fill it with scathing comments explaining why it was necessary.

Or you could use reflection, something roughly like this:

```
Dim methods = GetType(WhatEverTheType).GetMethods()
Dim doSomethingMethod = methods.Single(Function(method As MethodInfo)
        Return method.Name = "DoSomething" _
        And Not method.GetParameters()(0).ParameterType.IsByRef
    End Function)
doSomethingMethod.Invoke(instanceOfWhatEverTheType)
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the only way would be to force the call to the API using Reflection. Although I am not completely sure if that would work.

The problem is that creating 2 overloads only differing by `ref` is not CLS compliant and therefore not guaranteed to work in all .NET languages. To prevent getting into this situation, you should add the [CLSCompliantAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/ck7ah248(v=vs.105)) to your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file and then the compiler will warn you when you have broken CLS compatibility.

```
[assembly: System.CLSCompliant(true)]
```

A way you could fix this is by adding a wrapper function that can be called via VB.NET.

```
bool DoSomething(Object obj){};
bool DoSomething(ref Object obj){};

// Call this method from VB.NET
bool DoSomething2(ref Object obj)
{
    return DoSomething(ref obj);
}
```

There are a few different ways you could make this cleaner, such as making a separate assembly to wrap it as Scott Hannen mentioned, or simply by making the wrapper method for CLS compliance an extension method.

Comment: Adding a wrapper function wouldn't break the existing API, just extend it.